# Recover deleted ext4 after reinstall

Tags: 22.04, data-recovery, 23.10

So, I reset my PC from Ubuntu 22.04 to Kubuntu 23.10 and forgot to backup the Apache2 HTML files. Is there any way to recover these after a format?

Comment: Nope, you need  a backup. tools like testdisk only work if you do nothing after deleting; any other action (like format + install) is 1 action too much,  Take the time to redo your system: create a personal partition, use that for your website files and a symlink to connect it to ./www/html/

Answer (score -1):

Schematic layout of a just created system disk:

`<partition table>`
`<table of contents>`
`<First file>`
`<second file>`
`...`
`<file n>`
`free space`

1. if you just re-partitioned
   What happened: The partition table and table of contents got cleared.
   Running file recovery software has a high probability of success.
2. Any more operations than 1. and your success rate will diminish.
   Writing any of or all the files required for a new version of operating system will overwrite major portions of the earlier files.
   The more there is written, the lesser the success rate of any recovery operations will be.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the voting on this answer. Maybe the "Running file recovery software has a high probability of success" phrase isn't specific enough, and the voter was expecting a detailed example of how to use a specific file recovery tool like testdisk.

Comment: It appears to me that "I don't LIKE that" is a reason to down-vote, for some people... i.e. regardless of level of the answer.